# Dedicated Backup only replica in AlwaysOn SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, alwayson

I have an availability group with 3 replicas, as below:

```
Node1: Sync Commit, Automatic Failover
Node2: Sync Commit, Automatic Failover
Node3: (Sync or Async) Commit, <===================I do not want this node to become Primary replica
```

In the abovementioned list, I want to make use of `Node3`, as dedicated backup node, which will **never** become the primary node(*except when both Node 1 and Node2 are down*), but is responsible for taking backups from my database(s). Is it possible to do this using AlwaysOn and Windows Failover Cluster?

I know that I can exclude nodes from participating in backup by configuring them in backup priority section, and I can exclude `Node1` and `Node2`, but this will not **prevent** `Node3`, from being Primary node(*Node3 can become as a primary node, whenever BOTH Node1 and Node2 are down*). I think I should manage it via Windows Failover Cluster, but I do not know how...!

Event if I use AlwaysOn Availability Groups, how can I **prevent** Node3 from becoming a Primary node and also route the backups only to Node3, not any available secondary?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? If nodes 1 & 2 are down for whatever reason, why not have node 3 be able to take over the AG?

Comment: @BenThul I want to route my read-only requests to secondary, read/write requests to primary and backups to Node3. I do not want backups to be taken on any available secondary, except Node3. If Node 1 and Node 2, BOTH are down then Node 3 CAN act as primary. I have updated the question to clarify this

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with Failover Cluster (AlwaysOn Failover Clustering Instances) because a database can have only 1 active and running node across the FC.

What you need is [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15vvvvv). Here you can setup an async replicate where you can perform backups.

Comment: Using AlwaysOn Availability Groups, how can I  prevent a node from becoming a Primary node?

Comment: Here you can see some guidelines for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-backup-on-availability-replicas-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15